# Runing custom script (to populate model from CSV) from admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I am quite new to django and need help and ideas finding right way to do it. In short I have model which is populated few time a year from a CSV file (deleting all info and replacing it by new form file). To do that - I wrote script which is run from `shell`. It works, but not convenient and I cannot let to do it someone else. I would like to upgrade and make that script callable from `admin` page. This is what got so far:

To upload CSV file I created model for it (in `models.py`):

```
class DrgDuomenys(models.Model):

    drg_duomenys = models.FileField(upload_to='DRG_csv/')
    data = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

Model which should be populated (also in `models.py`):

```
class DRGkodas(models.Model):

    drg_kodas = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    drg_koeficientas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
    drg_skaicius = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.drg_kodas
```

Old script (named `ikelti_drg.py`) for populating model, activated from `shell` by writing `py manage.py ikelti_DRG  --path path/to/your/file.csv`

import csv
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from stv.models import DRGkodas, DrgDuomenys

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--path', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        path = kwargs['path']
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
            for row in reader:
                drg_kodai = DRGkodas.objects.create(
                    drg_kodas = str(row[0]),
                    drg_koeficientas = float(row[1]),
                    drg_skaicius = int(row[2]),
                )
```

I tried edit it to use CSV from database to simplify process, so my edited script which should be callable from `admin` page (probably incorrect, so any help here would be also appreciated):

```
import csv
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from stv.models import DRGkodas, DrgDuomenys

class LoadDrg(BaseCommand):
    #Load DRG duomenų csv file into the database

    data = DrgDuomenys.objects.latest('data')
    data_file = data.drg_duomenys 

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with open(data_file) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
            for row in reader:
                drg_kodai = DRGkodas.objects.create(
                    drg_kodas = str(row[0]),
                    drg_koeficientas = float(row[1]),
                    drg_skaicius = int(row[2]),
                )
```

Lastly I amended registered `DRGkodas` module in `admin.py` to include new-baked action like this:

```
from stv.management.commands.ikelti_DRG_admin import LoadDrg
class DRGkodaiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('drg_kodas', 'drg_koeficientas', 'drg_skaicius')
    actions = ['paskelbti_drg_info',]

    def paskelbti_drg_info(self, request):
        uzpildyti_drg = [LoadDrg]
    paskelbti_drg_info.short_description = "Upload new info"   
admin.site.register(DRGkodas, DRGkodaiAdmin)
```

Now the problem is, that to call action I have to choose at least one entry (and there should be none, since I am trying to create them) also if I create dummy entry and choose it to make command run, it (obviously) do not work.

**My main question would be what - correct way to do it?** At first I imagined that I should put button somewhere on admin page, but after some research I did not find anything solid on how to do that. So I tried to add action to model directly (my code above), but that work little bit different than I need.

**Please give me some advise on what approach I should use, also any literature or example code snippet would be very appreciated**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do things like these I use a button in the admin. To do that override the coresponding admin template (e.g. base_site.html if you want the button on the top) and add there something like:

```
<form action="/action_view" style="display:inline-block;">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Data" />

</form>
```

Then create the action_view and hook it up with your function in the url.

views.py:

```
def action_view(request):
    with open(data_file) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
        for row in reader:
            drg_kodai = DRGkodas.objects.create(
                drg_kodas = str(row[0]),
                drg_koeficientas = float(row[1]),
                drg_skaicius = int(row[2]),
            )
```

Add to url.py:

```
url(r'^action_view/$', action_view, name="action_view"),
```

Comment: That is exact result I wanted to achieve, but did not know where and how to start! If I could I upvote your answer twice!  Now I know what to look for, read some more literature and see much potential for future updates. Thank you.